# How to find percent change by row within groups python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lag, calculation

I have a sample of my dataframe as follows:

```
data = {'retailer': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        'store': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        'week':[2021110701, 2021101301, 2021100601, 2021092901, 2021092201, 2021110701, 2021101301, 2021100601, 2021092901, 2021092201],
        'dollars': [353136.2, 379263.8, 507892.1, 491528.2, 503602.8, 435025.2, 406698.5, 338383.5, 360845.1, 372385.2]
       }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have sorted my columns by doing

```
data = data.sort_values(['retailer', 'store', 'week'], ascending=(True, True, False))
```

I would like to find the percent different in dollars between each row WITHIN each group...so essentially group by retailer, then store and then find the percent difference between the rows for 'dollars' between the week and the week below it, and then save the value in a column next to the dollars.

Basically have the output look like:

```
data = {'retailer': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        'store': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        'week':[2021110701, 2021101301, 2021100601, 2021092901, 2021092201, 2021110701, 2021101301, 2021100601, 2021092901, 2021092201],
        'dollars': [353136.2, 379263.8, 507892.1, 491528.2, 503602.8, 435025.2, 406698.5, 338383.5, 360845.1, 372385.2],
        'pc_diff': [-0.06889030801252315, -0.2532591075939161, 0.03329188437204613, -0.02397643539710259, 'NaN', 0.06965036753270545, 0.20188632128930636, -0.062247208012523876, -0.030989684874694362, 'NaN']
       }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So for retailer 2, store 1 trying to find the percent difference between week `2021110701` and `2021101301` which would be `(353136.2 - 379263.8)/379263.8`.

The NAs exist because there is no row below that one so there is nothing to find the percent change between (if that makes sense). Is there a way I can do this/is there a pandas equivalent of using a lag function?

Comment: Your data is invalid, please provide a DataFrame constructor and check that it works ;)

Comment: should work now

Comment: Thanks @Jane I provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`+`pct_change`:

```
data.groupby(['retailer', 'store'])['dollars'].pct_change(-1)
```

output:

```
   retailer  store        week   dollars   pc_diff
0         2      1  2021110701  353136.2 -0.068890
1         2      1  2021101301  379263.8 -0.253259
2         2      1  2021100601  507892.1  0.033292
3         2      1  2021092901  491528.2 -0.023976
4         2      1  2021092201  503602.8       NaN
5         5      7  2021110701  435025.2  0.069650
6         5      7  2021101301  406698.5  0.201886
7         5      7  2021100601  338383.5 -0.062247
8         5      7  2021092901  360845.1 -0.030990
9         5      7  2021092201  372385.2       NaN
```