# How to calculate percentage change within a group and across a group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have seen multiple posts asking this question but have been unable to get the to work with my dataset.

I have a dataframe containing summary information (output from a `.groupby` and `describe()` operation).

```
data = [
    [123456, "2017", 8.0, 150.235],
    [123456, "2018", 8.0, 202.5],
    [123456, "2019", 7.0, 168.526],
    [123456, "2020", 6.0, 175.559],
    [123456, "2021", 8.0, 206.667],
    [789101, "2017", 8.0, 228.9],
    [789101, "2018", 5.0, 208]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "ID",
        "year",
        "count",
        "mean",
    ],
)
df
```

[image]

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Calculate the percentage change within `ID` from `year` to `year`.
2. Calculate the percentage change across `ID`, i.e from the first `year` to the latest `year` what is the overall percentage change.

Things I've tried:

1. `df["pct_ch"] = df.groupby(["ID", "year"])["mean"].apply(pd.Series.pct_change) + 1` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543223), unfortunately this returns a column of all `NaN`.
2. `df["pct_change"] = df.groupby(["ID", "year"])["mean"].pct_change(-1)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828840/how-to-find-percent-change-by-row-within-groups-python-pandas), which also returns a column of all `NaN` values.

I am curious what I am doing wrong (why am I getting all `NaN` and how I can calculate these percentage change columns?

Ideal output would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: you can simply use: ' df['pct_change_by_year']=df['mean'].pct_change()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't group by year, and you can just `groupby.pct_change` directly:

```
df['pct_ch'] = df.groupby('ID')['mean'].pct_change()
```

By setting year as group, you groups contain only **one** row, and there is nothing to compute.

Output:

```
       ID  year  count     mean    pct_ch
0  123456  2017    8.0  150.235       NaN
1  123456  2018    8.0  202.500  0.347888
2  123456  2019    7.0  168.526 -0.167773
3  123456  2020    6.0  175.559  0.041732
4  123456  2021    8.0  206.667  0.177194
5  789101  2017    8.0  228.900       NaN
6  789101  2018    5.0  208.000 -0.091306
```

For the overall percentage change use a custom function:

```
df['pct_ch_overall'] = df.groupby('ID')['mean']. transform(lambda g: g.iloc[[0, -1]].pct_change())
```

Output:

```
       ID  year  count     mean    pct_ch  pct_ch_overall
0  123456  2017    8.0  150.235       NaN             NaN
1  123456  2018    8.0  202.500  0.347888             NaN
2  123456  2019    7.0  168.526 -0.167773             NaN
3  123456  2020    6.0  175.559  0.041732             NaN
4  123456  2021    8.0  206.667  0.177194        0.375625
5  789101  2017    8.0  228.900       NaN             NaN
6  789101  2018    5.0  208.000 -0.091306       -0.091306
```

Comment: NB. You need to multiply by 100 to get percentages like yours